# Node JS async module initialization patterns

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to asynchrounisly get some data during module startup and save returned value as top level variable. And other methods of module should not be called before this variable has been initialized.

So basically I need something like this:

```
myModule.js
===========

// i can't use await here...
const importantData = await fetch('/my-service'); 

exports.myMethod = function () {
    // do something with importantData
}
```

So,

1. Top level `importantData` is promise
2. If someone call `myMethod` method then it should defer it's execution until top level const is resolved
3. I don't want to use `let`

What is the elegant way to sove this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Make every exported function an `async` function that internally `awaits` the resolution of the initialization fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make `myMethod` asynchronous:

```
const importantDataPromise = fetch('/my-service'); 

exports.myMethod = async function () {
    const importantData = await importantDataPromise;
    ... // Do stuff with importantData.
}
```